# jQuery disable hover with click

Tags: jquery, click, hover

I have a jQuery code, that is working as I expect it to work to a certain point.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PXzsc/11/) is the fiddle

Three menu items, when hovered over, a black square and additional info appears in the yellow box. 
When clicked menu 1 & 3, a green circle appears before the menu. 
When clicked menu 2, a search bar appears also and gets in focus with a little bit of delay.

Until this point everything is fine.

What I want is, for example:

-when 'menu_item'_2 is clicked and I move away the mouse over another item, in the yellow field 'info_2' must be shown.

So I should somehow drop the hover after a click has been made.
And when I click another menu_item it should show the corresponding info in the yellow box.

I'm not an expert in jQuery, so maybe the code is must be done some other way.

Anyway, thanks for your help!

```
$(function() {

$("#search").hover( 
    function() {
        $("#search_info").show();
        $("#arrow").show().css('top', 230);
        $("#fade_search").animate({ opacity: 0.4},50);
    },
    function() {
        $("#arrow, #search_info").hide();
        $("#fade_search").animate({ opacity: 1},50);       
    }).click(function(e) { 
             $("#activated").show().css('top', 232);
             var focusDelay = $("input[type=text]").fadeIn(100);            
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     $(focusDelay).focus();
                 },1000);
             e.preventDefault();
            });

$("#list").hover( 
    function() {
        $("#list_info").show();
        $("#arrow").show().css('top', 205);
        $("#fade_list").animate({ opacity: 0.4},50);
    },
    function() {
        $("#arrow, #list_info").hide();
        $("#fade_list").animate({ opacity: 1},50);

    }).click(function(e) {  show up
             $("#activated").show().css('top', 209 );
             e.preventDefault();
            });

$("#program").hover( 
    function() {
          $("#program_info").show();
          $("#arrow").show().css('top', 255);
          $("#fade_program").animate({ opacity: 0.4},50);
      },
    function() {
          $("#arrow, #program_info").hide();
          $("#fade_program").animate({ opacity: 1},50);

    }).click(function(e) {
             $("#activated").show().css('top', 261 );
             e.preventDefault();
             });
});
```

Comment: Just to get some clarification: the text should not be displaying on hover after you have clicked any of the menu items once, instead it should then be activated only on menu clicks?

Comment: yes, that is true. after click it should show the text of the corresponding menu item.

Comment: I'm working on a clean solution with clear examples, just hold out a bit more. :)

Comment: thanks, I'm looking forward to see it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your entire jQuery code. See this jsFiddle for the rework: http://jsfiddle.net/jUHNF/8/

Note: I assumed you wanted to only show the search box for menu item 2, if that's not the case, just remove the following:

```
    else {
        $("input[type=text]").hide();
    }
```

The code itself should be pretty well commented (maybe a bit too well).

As you can see I have moved all functions into ONE hover/click event, instead of making them into separate events depending on what menu item you clicked on. The idea here is to keep it clean and simple.

What if you want to make further changes to your menu clicks (for example make the currently clicked item *italic*)? Then you would need to make the change in three places, once for each menu event. If you add a new menu item you would need to duplicate the code once more as well... and so on. By making sure that most of your logic can go under the same event you won't have to duplicate code like this (Don't Repeat Yourself!)

**Edit:** Pasting jsFiddle code for future reference.

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="modes">
            <div class="elements" id="list">
                <a href="">menu_item_1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="elements" id="search">
                <a class="link" href="">menu_item_2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="elements" id="program">
                <a href="">menu_item_3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="infobox">
            <p id="list_info" class="infobox">
                info_1
            </p>
            <p id="search_info"class="infobox">
                info_2
            </p>
            <p id="program_info"class="infobox">
                info_3
            </p>
        <form method="post" action=""></form>
            <input type="text" name="search_field"
            placeholder="type here" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id="arrow"></div>
        <div id="activated"></div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".elements").mouseover(
        function() {
            activateMenuItem($(this));
        }
    ).click(function(e) {
        var bulletTop = $(this).position().top + 207; 
        $("#activated").show().css("top", bulletTop);

        //turn off the hover function for all menu items
        $(".elements").off("hover"); 

        if($(this).attr("id") == "search") {
             var focusDelay = $("input[type=text]").fadeIn(100);            
             setTimeout(function(){
                 $(focusDelay).focus();
             },1000);
        }else {
            $("input[type=text]").hide();
        }
        activateMenuItem($(this)); //do same as on hover
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function activateMenuItem(item) {
            var arrowTop = item.position().top + 205;
            var boxName = "#" + item.attr("id") + "_info";              
            $("#arrow").show().css("top", arrowTop);
            $(".infobox").hide();
            $(boxName).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, that's exactly what I wanted! yes I knew it from the beginning that this should be done in one event I just couldn't figure out how (I' a newbie at this).

Comment: I tried, but it says, I need 15 reputations to upvote :/

and a weird thing, your fiddle stopped working properly. when I first checked it was working and now it doesn't :S

Comment: Ah! Nevermind that then. Try this updated link, I think it reverted back to an old version somehow: http://jsfiddle.net/jUHNF/8/

Comment: Aye, but the one I just linked (update 8) has a bit tidier code. :)

Comment: but I'm not sure why, it doesn't do the same as the 6th version.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").hover( //hover over search triggers info and arrow to show up
    function() {
        $("#search_info").show();
        $("#arrow").show().css('top', 230);
        $("#fade_search").animate({
            opacity: 0.4
        },
        50);
    },
    function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('activated')) {
            $("#arrow, #search_info").hide();
        }
        $("#fade_search").animate({
            opacity: 1
        },
        50);
    }).click(function(e) { //click on search triggers search box and activated button to show up
        $('.elements').removeClass('activated');
        $(this).addClass('activated');
        $("#activated").show().css('top', 232);
        var focusDelay = $("input[type=text]").fadeIn(100);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(focusDelay).focus();
        },
        1000);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#list").hover( //hover over list triggers info and arrow to show up
    function() {
        $("#list_info").show();
        $("#arrow").show().css('top', 205);
        $("#fade_list").animate({
            opacity: 0.4
        },
        50);
    },
    function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('activated')) {
            $("#arrow, #list_info").hide();
        }
        $("#fade_list").animate({
            opacity: 1
        },
        50);
    }).click(function(e) { //click on list triggers search box and activated button to show up
        $('.elements').removeClass('activated');
        $(this).addClass('activated');
        $("#activated").show().css('top', 209);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#program").hover( //hover over program triggers info and arrow to show up
    function() {
        $("#program_info").show();
        $("#arrow").show().css('top', 255);
        $("#fade_program").animate({
            opacity: 0.4
        },
        50);
    },
    function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('activated')) {
            $("#arrow, #program_info").hide();
        }
        $("#fade_program").animate({
            opacity: 1
        },
        50);
    }).click(function(e) {
        $('.elements').removeClass('activated');
        $(this).addClass('activated');
        $("#activated").show().css('top', 261);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
$('.elements').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('activated')) {
        var i = $(e.currentTarget).index();
        $('#infobox p').hide();
        $('#arrow, #infobox p:eq(' + i + ')').show();
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PXzsc/14/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, as it duplicates the currently visible info text (display two at a time).

Comment: thanks for the answer. that is almost there, but on hover after click, the info on right still shows up on hover. and the black square moves on hover too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/workdreamer/TqxyY/

Comment: thanks, but same problem, after click on hover still showing the contents of the other items

Comment: Ok please check again the link i provided. i think is that what you want.

Comment: it does the same. e.g. after clicking 'menu_item_1' and after hovering over other elements, the black box shouldn't move and the content in the yellow box should show info_1, until another element is clicked.

Comment: thanks for your time, this one still not working, but
Anders made what I wanted: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jUHNF/6/